# Order of UIImageViews

Tags: xcode, random, uiimageview, layer

I am making a card game where the player can touch and drag around 3 UIImageViews, lets say from top to bottom ImageA, ImageB, ImageC. My problem is that the order is always the same, so even when the player passes one card over the other ImageA will be always on top. Is there anyway to randomize which card will be on top of the stack?
Thanks in advance.

p.s. If i knew coding in Cocos2d i would use layers, but i don't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
[[self superview] bringSubviewToFront:self];}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: How about getting them lower in a stack?

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the layering (z-index/layer) of your UIImageViews with the following code `theView.layer.zPosition = x`

x is a numerical value. The higher the more predominant/upper/to the front the layer is. Default value for UIImages is 0.

Note: You need to use the QuartzCore framework to utilise this method but it is extremely easy and useful. Just pop this line in your header file.

`#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h`